# how to get all innerHTML when only $eval gives results ($$ returns undefined)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

There is a table that I'm trying to pull 3 info from each row. Once done it would scroll to the bottom of the page click "load more" and then scrape the new data, and so on and so forth until there is no more "load more" button.

To pull all of the data from the table I used $$eval but that results in an undefined. However I get data if I use $eval instead but that only pulls data from the first row of the table. Why is $$eval returning "undefined" and if I can't use it how can I loop through the table to get all values with $eval?

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // default is true
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('someexamplesite.com', {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });

  const ExerciseName = await page.$$eval(
    '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(2) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a',
    (e) => e.innerText
  );

  const muscleTargeted = await page.$$eval(
    ' .ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(2) > .ExResult-cell > .ExResult-muscleTargeted > a',
    (e) => e.innerText
  );

  const equipmentType = await page.$$eval(
    '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(2) > .ExResult-cell > .ExResult-equipmentType > a',
    (e) => e.innerText
  );

  //click on load more
  await page.waitForSelector(
    '#js-ex-content > #js-ex-category-body > .ExCategory-results > .ExLoadMore > .bb-flat-btn'
  );

  console.log({ ExerciseName, muscleTargeted, equipmentType });

    await browser.close();
})().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

**code that I'm trying to scrape**

```
<div class="ExCategory-results">
    <div class="ExCategory-resultsLoadIndicator" id="js-ex-finder-load-indicator">
      <div class="ExCategory-resultsLoadIndicatorBox">
        <div class="ExCategory-resultsLoadIndicatorSpinner bb-spinner-btn__spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
        
          <div class="ExResult-row  flexo-container flexo-between" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
            <div class="ExResult-cell ">
                <!-- using male photos -->
                <img class="ExImg ExResult-img  ls-is-cached lazyloaded" width="70" height="70" onerror="if (window._E_) _E_(this)" alt=" thumbnail image" src="https://www.websites.com/exercises/exerciseImages/sequences/742/Male/m/742_1.jpg" data-src="https://www.websites.com/exercises/exerciseImages/sequences/742/Male/m/742_1.jpg" itemprop="image">
            </div>
            <div class="ExResult-cell ExResult-cell--nameEtc">
              <h3 class="ExHeading ExResult-resultsHeading">
                <a href="/exercises/rickshaw-carry" itemprop="name">
                  Rickshaw Carry
                </a>
              </h3>
              <div class="ExResult-details ExResult-muscleTargeted">
                Muscle Targeted:
                <a href="/exercises/muscle/forearms">
                  Forearms
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType">
                Equipment Type:
                <a href="/exercises/equipment/other">
                  Other
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ExResult-cell ExResult-cell--rating">
              <div class="ExRating">
                <div class="ExRating-badge">
                  9.6
                </div>
                <div class="ExRating-description ExRating-description--Average">
                  Average
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>        
        
          <div class="ExResult-row  flexo-container flexo-between" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
            <div class="ExResult-cell ">
                <!-- using male photos -->
                <img class="ExImg ExResult-img  ls-is-cached lazyloaded" width="70" height="70" onerror="if (window._E_) _E_(this)" alt=" thumbnail image" src="https://www.websites.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-50m-single-leg-leg-press-m1-square-600x600.jpg" data-src="https://www.websites.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-50m-single-leg-leg-press-m1-square-600x600.jpg" itemprop="image">
            </div>
            <div class="ExResult-cell ExResult-cell--nameEtc">
              <h3 class="ExHeading ExResult-resultsHeading">
                <a href="/exercises/single-leg-press" itemprop="name">
                  Single-Leg Press
                </a>
              </h3>
              <div class="ExResult-details ExResult-muscleTargeted">
                Muscle Targeted:
                <a href="/exercises/muscle/quadriceps">
                  Quadriceps
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType">
                Equipment Type:
                <a href="/exercises/equipment/machine">
                  Machine
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ExResult-cell ExResult-cell--rating">
              <div class="ExRating">
                <div class="ExRating-badge">
                  9.6
                </div>
                <div class="ExRating-description ExRating-description--Average">
                  Average
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thank you and I also posted a snipped of the code that i'm trying to scrape

Comment: can you show the thing that's going wrong, rather than the thing that works? If `$$eval` fails, please show what code you were using that _doesn't_ work so that we can tell you what you might have been doing wrong. Also, remember that if you're including code, try to make it a [mcve] because right now you're showing a lot of JS and markup beyond what you need to show off the problem.

Comment: I updated it with the $$eval. I didn't know how much of the page that I wanted to scrape to past. Next time I'll just post 2 divs of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-frameevalselector-pagefunction-args) method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` in the background so what you get is an array. You can't apply `(e) => e.innerText` on an array directly (even if it has a length of `1`) without iterating it or getting the right elements by their proper indexes (e.g.: `e[0].innerText`), otherwise you will get `undefined`.

You can use an [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the matching elements and collect the `innerText` of each into an array.

```js
const exerciseName = await page.$$eval(
    '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(2) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a',
    elements => elements.map(el => el.innerText)
  )
```

Output:

```js
[ 'Rickshaw Carry' ]
```

---

***Edit:***

You can iterate the row classes using a loop with an index (easiest to use a regular `for` loop) by (1) counting the elements with the same class names:

```js
const rowsCounts = await page.$$eval('.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row', rows => rows.length)
```

Then (2) iterate over the children `.ExResult-row:nth-child(n) ...`, and collect the `innerText`s to an array (`exerciseNames`):

```js
const exerciseNames = []
for (let i = 1; i < rowsCounts + 1; i++) { // you mignt need i = 2
  const exerciseName = await page.$eval(
    `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a`,
    el => el.innerText)
  exerciseNames.push(exerciseName)
}
```

Output:

```js
[
  'Rickshaw Carry',
  'Single-Leg Press',
  'Landmine twist',
  'Weighted pull-up',
  'T-Bar Row with Handle',
  'Palms-down wrist curl over bench'
]
```

*Note:* The loop should be started form `1` and not `0` in such cases, as there is no "nth-child(0)". In your example the 1st is missing as well, so you might need to start the iteration at `2`.

Comment: Thank you! Since $$eval does querySelectorAll how can I get it to return all of the innerText for the tables?

Comment: It is less to do with `querySelector` vs. `querySelectorAll` as the rows are siblings of each other so they don't share the very same selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). You seem to need `page.$eval` inside a loop. See my updated answer with an example.

Comment: I understand this more now & this worked. Thank you!

Comment: Hey I used the same code to add equipment  however for those it gives me 3x the data. as in it mentioned multiple different machines while all these exercises only have one machine. I don't know where it's coming from. I can not figure out why this is happening. If I should post it as a question instead of a comment could you please let me know and I will do so. Thank you

Comment: FIXED!  innerHTML fixes this. It does add some unwanted character such as "\n" but those could be fixed in excel.

Comment: Great to hear that you were able to solve it. You can cleanup your results from linebreaks (those are the \n-s) and other unwanted patterns with string.replace() in your javascript code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: that's exactly what I needed! Thank you!